# How to test my app in 1.6 android

Tags: android, emulation, android-virtual-device

I'm trying to test my app in the 1.6 platform, but I can't even choose an emulator from the devices list in Run Configurations. Here's my Manifest:

```
<uses-sdk android:targetSdkVersion="8"
android:minSdkVersion="4"/>
```

I don't see why I'm unable to choose an emulator which is set up for 1.6. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you haven't posted the manifest.
In order to run emulator 1.6, go to Run->Run Configurations->Target and select "Manual" instead of "Automatic".
That way Eclipse will prompt you which emulator you want.

Comment: sorry, but no it is not, how did i forget to say that :D

Comment: Ok, but what happens exactly when you try to run your project? Do you get any error?

Comment: I got it fixed. But i had to start the 1.6 emulator and then choose that emulator when running the app manually. If i went to Run Configurations to choose the 1.6 emulator, these wouldn't show in the list. So i hope my app is visible for 1.6 users on the Market.